# Having trouble enabling full_output in ODEINT

Tags: python, arrays, odeint, keyerror

Enabling full_output should be a trivial task, yet, as usual the problem is somewhat complex.
Unfortunately, there isn't any easy way of describing my problem, other than to show you my code.

```
y_initial = pylab.array([th1,th2,th3,phi1,phi2,phi3])
t = pylab.arange(0.0, tmax, dt)
ylist = odeint (derivs, y_initial, t)

th1 = [ylist[j][0] for j in range(0,len(t))]
th2 = [ylist[j][1] for j in range(0,len(t))]
th3 = [ylist[j][2] for j in range(0,len(t))]
phi1 = [ylist[j][3] for j in range(0,len(t))]
phi2 = [ylist[j][4] for j in range(0,len(t))]
phi3 = [ylist[j][5] for j in range(0,len(t))]
```

Writing odeint (derivs, y_initial, t, full_output = 0) causes no issue but
writing odeint (derivs, y_initial, t, full_output = 1) gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
th1 = [ylist[j][0] for j in range(0,len(t))]
KeyError: 0
```

I assume this error is happening because of the way I have defined the odeint (with an array and such). Would this issue be solved if I were to create a loop to calculate the odeint values and store them in an array THEN let it proceed to the next line? If so what would such code look like?

If you don't understand whay I've written it in such a weird way here's why:

```
def dth2dt (t,th1,th2,th3,phi1,phi2,phi3):
    return *some math dependent on switching the six variables around*

def dphi2dt (t,th1,th2,th3,phi1,phi2,phi3):
    return **some math dependent on switching the six variables around**

def derivs(y,t):

    dydt[0] = dth2dt(t,y[2],y[1],y[0],y[5],y[4],y[3])
    dydt[3] = dphi2dt(t,y[2],y[1],y[0],y[5],y[4],y[3])

    dydt[1] = dth2dt(t,y[0],y[1],y[2],y[3],y[4],y[5])
    dydt[4] = dphi2dt(t,y[0],y[1],y[2],y[3],y[4],y[5])

    dydt[2] = dth2dt(t,y[1],y[2],y[0],y[4],y[5],y[3])
    dydt[5] = dphi2dt(t,y[1],y[2],y[0],y[4],y[5],y[3])

    return dydt
```

I hope it is evident to you that this method enables me to switch variables around without having to write out the math repeatedly. But now I can't enable full_output in odeint.

Thank you for your time, and I thank you for your response!

Ryu

Answer (score 2):

The output of odeint is different depending on whether full_output is False or True. You're used to the behavior when full_output is disabled. When it is enabled, the output is a tuple (u, d), where u is the solution to your differential equations and d is the dictionary of output provided by full_output. The key_error arises because what you're referring to as ylist is this tuple, not just the ode results you were expecting. If you change,

```
ylist = odeint (derivs, y_initial, t)
```

to

```
(ylist, d) = odeint (derivs, y_initial, t, full_output=True)
```

you should get the ylist you expect.